# Problema com formulário de cadastro com modal

Tags: html, bootstrap, modal

- No formulário de cadastro chamo uma janela `modal` que é a mesma página de listar itens cadastrados.
- Na hora que clico no `submit` do `form` ele envia para meu banco de dados beleza e fecha o `modal`.

Porém, para eu ver a mudança na tela, é necessário dar um `refresh` na página. Como posso clicar no `submit` e ao mesmo tempo dar um `refresh` na página?

Tentei assim, mas ficou dando `refresh` direto!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",2000);
  function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",2000);
  }
</script> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetTimeout()">Cadastrar</button>
```

---

```
<!--Butao adicionar -->
<button href="#my-modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+ Adicionar</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Adicionar G&aacute;s </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="" id="quick-post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Nome">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Pre&ccedil;o</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="preco">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label> </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" name="image-uploader" id="img-upload">
            <img height="80" width="80" id="image-preview" src="" style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="normal">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label></label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: É só fazer `location.reload()` depois que você fecha o modal.

Comment: Como ficaria no javascript poderia me dar essa forca ai ?

Comment: Você falou isso "na hora que clico no submit do form ele envia para meu banco de dados blz e fecha o modal.". Cadê o código que faz o submit e fecha o modal ?

Comment: Vou colocar aqui em baixo

Comment: É para editar e colocar na sua pergunta, jovem. E outra, não é o código que salva. Esse é o HTML. Cadê o JS ?

Comment: `refresh` no `submit` não vai ajudar a mostrar o que ainda não está cadastrado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça a atualização ao fechar o `modal`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     window.location = window.location;
   });
</script>
```